# Android Screen fixed for different sizes

Tags: android

I want to create a project that runs on different android devices. My UI should customize according to screen size. how can I do this ?
[image: in my phone] 
[image: in my tablet]

I want to make my app's appearance like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create layout folders in resource folder of the project for different sizes/dimensions,
Create layout folders:

Below are the name of folders with device density,

```
layout-ldpi            (low) ~120dpi
layout-mdpi            (medium) ~160dpi
layout-hdpi            (high) ~240dpi
layout-xhdpi           (extra-high) ~320dpi
layout-xxhdpi          (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
layout-xxxhdpi         (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

Don't forget to concern the below link,

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

This helps you alot....!

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your images for every screen density with Android studio. Right click on image from drawable folder then choose New/Image Asset/Ok.